# Efficient way to convert Dataframe to RDD in Scala/SPARK?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, rdd

I have a `dataFrame = [CUSTOMER_ID ,itemType, eventTimeStamp, valueType]` which I convert to `RDD[(String, (String, String, Map[String, Int]))]` by doing the following:

```
 val tempFile = result.map( {
     r => {
         val customerId = r.getAs[String]( "CUSTOMER_ID" )
         val itemType = r.getAs[String]( "itemType" )
         val eventTimeStamp = r.getAs[String]( "eventTimeStamp" )
         val valueType = r.getAs[Map[String, Int]]( "valueType" )
         (customerId, (itemType, eventTimeStamp, valueType))
          }
          } )
```

Since my my input is huge, this takes much time. Is there any efficient way to convert the `df` to `RDD[(String, (String, String, Map[String, Int]))]` ?

Comment: How big is your input?

Comment: How long does it take to convert the DataFrame into a RDD?

Comment: Did you try setting different number of partitions on the DataFrame? Does it make any difference?

Comment: Did you try to use just result.rdd, without using .map()? Does it produce a similar result? Does it run faster?

Comment: Inout size is 7TB

Comment: @RomiKuntsman If I use .rdd I still need to use .map right ? I am new to Scala, so sorry if my question is ignorant, just curious .

Comment: Try to use just .rdd and see what do you get, in terms of structure and speed

Answer (score 2):

The operation you've described is as cheap as it's going to get.  Doing a few `getAs` and allocating a few tuples is almost free.  If it's going slow, that's probably unavoidable due to your large data size (7T).  Also note that Catalyst optimizations cannot be performed on RDDs, so including this kind of `.map` downstream of DataFrame operations will often prevent other Spark shortcuts.